# Can nopcommerce front end and admin panel be hosted on different servers?

Tags: sql-server, model-view-controller, server, nopcommerce

I am new in nopcommerce project. 
I want to know that can nopcommerce front end and admin panel be hosted on different servers ??

Comment: Do you want to host front end on one server and admin panel on another?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? They are two seperate projects (Nop.Web and Nop.Admin). Both have references to Nop.Core, Nop.Data, Nop.Services and Nop.Web.Framework, so those libraries should be deployed on both servers. I can not think of a reason why you would want to do such a thing.